# Error while Importing StackMob sdk into libraries (related to annotations.jar or dalvik?)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dalvik, stackmob

When I want to use StackMob sdk I'm giving the error which I share below. It appears only while compiling process. I checked all similar questions related to this situation before asking however they did not solve my problem.

According to general opinion it might be caused by importing external jars twice implicitly. But I checked 100 times maybe but there are no any jar file used with the same name twice.

Ps: I'm using Intellij Idea as IDE.

```
Android Dex: [POF] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Android Dex: [POF] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;
Android Dex: [POF] at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
Android Dex: [POF] at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
Android Dex: [POF] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
Android Dex: [POF] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
```

Comment: Did you make sure to get the latest jar? (http://support.stackmob.com/entries/22068868-android-sdk-and-adt-r17)

Comment: I downloaded it just 2 hours ago from the official stockmob page. It must be the latest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be something with the latest facebook jar, which we bundle. I'm looking into it, but in the meantime, here's a jar without facebook integrated. You can still use facebook features, but you'll need to include the FB code yourself

https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.stackmob.com/sdks/android/stackmob-android-sdk-1.1.1-nofb.jar

Comment: with latest jar my problem has been solved. Thank you stackmob team. this is the link https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.stackmob.com/sdks/android/stackmob-android-sdk-1.1.1.jar